# Mono C# SQL Update "Concurrency violation"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, mono

Every time I try to update a row via SqlDataAdapter.Update() in Mono, I get:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.DBConcurrencyException: Concurrency violation:
>   the UpdateCommand affected 0 records.
>     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update (System.Data.DataRow[] dataRows, Sy
>   stem.Data.Common.DataTableMapping tableMapping) [0x00000]

The related C# code is:

```
IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DB_CONN);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

conn.Open();

IDbCommand command  = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TestTable";

SqlDataAdapter    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter((SqlCommand)command);
SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

adapter.Fill(ds);
ds.Tables[0].TableName = "TestTable";
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["testInt"] = 5;

adapter.Update(ds, "TestTable");
```

After logging the query as it hits SQL Server 2008, it shows:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [TestUpdate] SET [id] = @p1, [testInt] = @p2 WHERE (([id] = @p3) AND ((@p4 = 1 AND [testInt] IS NULL) OR ([testInt] = @p5)))', N'@p1 int, @p2 int, @p3 int, @p4 int, @p5 int',  @p1=1, @p2=5, @p3=1, @p4=NULL, @p5=NULL
```

The database is a simple test to debug this issue, composed of two columns: an integer id column (pk) and integer testInt column, with nulls allowed. The code works fine unless the testInt value is NULL, in which case the exeption is thrown.

```
UPDATE [TestUpdate]
   SET [id]      = 1,
       [testInt] = 5
 WHERE (([id] = 1) 
        AND ((NULL = 1 AND [testInt] IS NULL)
             OR ([testInt] = NULL)))
```

It appears @p4 should be 1 in this scenario, as to apply the IS NULL check, as opposed to NULL which results in an = NULL check (which I believe would fail if the value was NULL).

Does this looks like a Mono issue to anyone else, or am I just doing something silly/wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would suggest running the code on .Net and capture its query to SQL Server.  If it differs from what Mono has, then it sounds like a bug in Mono.

If it is, please file it at:
http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs

with your test case so it can fixed.

Comment: I've filed a related bug https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=522624

Although the original bug doesn't seem fully reproducible for everyone. Given that, I was more hoping if anyone else had encountered it or would know a workaround.